# Создание аналога существующего приложения

Tags: лицензирование, права, архитектура

Имеется некая программа для гос. учреждения, рекомендованная министерством, ведомству которого подчинено данное учреждение. Вопрос: можно ли создать и внедрить свою программу, которая полностью соответствует министерской? Т.е будет полностью переделана БД (это нужно для интеграции с другой программой. т.к. в данный момент пользователи выполняют двойную работу - забивают инфу в одной, а потом ту же инфу в другой). Поэтому я и хочу их слить воедино.

Отвлеченный пример - имеется 1с, рекомендованная министерством финансов. Можно ли написать такую же 1с и пользоваться своей самоделкой? Функционал будет соответствовать оригинальной 1с.

С точки зрения законности это возможно? И какие формальности необходимо соблюсти, чтоб никаких проблем не возникало. Если кто-либо когда-то сталкивался с подобной проблемой, прошу написать и посоветовать...

Информация, которой оперируют эти программы, относится к классу особо конфиденциальной.

Comment: это будет правомерным до тех пор пока 1с специалисты не начнут вас давить патентами. почему это вдруг ваша программа делает все то что и 1с (хотя реальность этого зависит от функций вашей программы). хороший пример многие топ компании оракл, самсунг, еппл, майкрософт, итд итп.

с другой стороны программа это не просто функционал, - это еще гарантия того что она будет работать. в случае если что-то случится ваша голова будет на плахе поэтому я б дважды подумал :)

Answer (score 2):

> Вопрос: можно ли создать и внедрить свою программу, которая полностью соответствует министерской?

Да, возможно создать полный аналог программного обеспечения.
Примерами практически полный аналог с точки зрения функциональностей - MS Office и OpenOffice, Windows и ReactOS.
При создании OpenOffice и ReactOS строго избегалось использование "чужого" программного кода, дабы не создавать возможностей для споров по поводу авторских прав. Как видите, никаких проблем тут нет. Взять те же учетные системы - их тоже существует не один программный продукт, а множество. Поэтому можно сделать свое.

С другой стороны, по закону Вы имеете право адаптировать (но не модифицировать) программные продукты под себя. Разница между адаптацией и модификацией достаточно тонка, но это все регулируется законом.

http://www.internet-law.ru/law/pc/soft.htm

> адаптация программы для ЭВМ или базы данных - это внесение изменений, осуществляемых исключительно в целях обеспечения функционирования программы для ЭВМ или базы данных на конкретных технических средствах пользователя или под управлением конкретных программ пользователя;
> модификация (переработка) программы для ЭВМ или базы данных - это любые их изменения, не являющиеся адаптацией;

и ниже

> Статья 15. Свободное воспроизведение и адаптация программы для ЭВМ или базы данных
>
> 1. Лицо, правомерно владеющее экземпляром программы для ЭВМ или базы данных, вправе без получения дополнительного разрешения правообладателя осуществлять любые действия, связанные с функционированием программы для ЭВМ или базы данных в соответствии с ее назначением, в том числе запись и хранение в памяти ЭВМ, а также исправление явных ошибок. Запись и хранение в памяти ЭВМ допускаются в отношении одной ЭВМ или одного пользователя в сети, если иное не предусмотрено договором с правообладателем.
> 2. В изъятие из положений абзаца третьего статьи 10 настоящего Закона лицо, правомерно владеющее экземпляром программы для ЭВМ или базы данных, вправе без согласия правообладателя и без выплаты ему дополнительного вознаграждения:
>    осуществлять адаптацию программы для ЭВМ или базы данных;

Answer (score 1):

Не используйте чужой код и не будет никаких проблем

Comment: Но в целом никаких проблем с законом не возникнет - в том плане что по сути послали министерство и сделали свою прогу?

Comment: Это нужно уточнять у Вашего руководства. На каких основаниях используется министерская программа, существуют ли какие-нибудь договоренности и т.п.

Comment: Боюсь руководство тут сказать ничего не может. На все вопросы разводит руками -типа не помним, а искать времени нет. Правильно ли будет с точки зрения закона - то же не знают - тк учреждение от ИТ стоит так далеко как ..... 
Я вот счас "переписываю программу одну сделанную в далеких 90 (похожа на FAR синий экран.

Answer (score 1):

Здравствуйте. По поводу законности вам уже все сказали, опишу лишь этапы, которых вам скорее всего не избежать.

1. **согласование с руководством** - самый проблемный и долгий: пока обсудят целесообразность, пока получат разрешение свыше пройдет много времени. Я бы начал именно с этого пункта, т.к. если все встанет именно на нем, то остальные не будут иметь никакого смысла. Тут очень важна личная заинтересованность начальства. Им нужно продемонстрировать конкретные плюсы вашего продукта, например, такие, как экономия времени (а следовательно и денег), повышение производительности труда и т.п. И еще будет очень неплохо заручиться поддержкой коллектива. Аргумент, что с программой будет работать проще и удобней, боюсь, может счесться несостоятельным, если его не развить.
2. **сертификация** - тут все достаточно просто, мы делали через [АНО "МИЦ"](http://testrussia.ru/).
3. **внедрение**

**Частный пример**: была одна гос. организация, в которой данные хранились в КУЧЕ dbf файлов, их было очень много и в сумме они занимали около терабайта. Было, если не ошибаюсь семь операторов - данные между ними были условно разбиты на равные части, т.к. ввиду ограничения не было возможности держать их на одном компьютере. Естественно, никакого доступа по сети... Клиент к этой свалке был написан на бейсике еще самим Царем Горохом.

Обратились они к нам с целью оптимизации рабочих процессов. Они были убеждены, что корень их бед находится в клиенте, хотели что-бы мы переписали его под windows, а "базу" оставили как есть. Так вот, хоть инициатива исходила от них, нам пришлось убеждать их не один месяц, что им просто необходима полная техническая реорганизация.

В конце концов они сдались, и мы им все сделали - данные перекинули в postgre, написали кроссплатформенного gui клиента, web интерфейс, полнотекстовый поиск, все дела. В результате они остались ОЧЕНЬ довольны нашим решением, да и мы тоже. Раньше поиск нужного документа занимал от 10 минут до нескольких часов, сейчас же секунду максимум.

Answer (score -1):

Я думаю, что можно. Но нужно понимать, что там за эти программные продукты уже давно всё проплачено и нужным людям дано "на лапу", чтобы эти программные продукты были внедрены и работали. Пусть людям нужно будет делать двойную работу, пусть они будут с багами и тормозить... но будут именно они.
А пожелать могу только успехов в начинаниях!